# spring boot: list all running @Async processes

Tags: spring-boot

Let's say I have this api example

```
public class MyApi {

    private final FooService fooService;

    public MyApi(FooService fooservice){
        this.fooService = fooservice;
    }

    @Post
    public void process(...) {
        fooService.process(...);
    }
    
    @Get
    public List<RunningProcesses> getAllRunningAsyncProcesses(){
        ...?
    }

    @Post
    public List<RunningProcesses> terminateAllRunningAsyncProcesses(){
        ...?
    }
    
}



@Service
public class FooService {
   
   @Async
   public CompletableFuture<String> process(...){
       String result = processing();
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
   }

}
```

I know that using a spring boot and @Async annotation I can assign long running tasks
to other threads. But is there any way to get a list of all currently running @Async
tasks and terminate tasks selectively? Does spring boot have any out of the box solution
on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the ThreadPullTaskExcecutor. Using that you can retrieve all the currently queued tasks by accessing the ThreadPoolExecutor's task queue. We then transform these tasks into RunningProcesses objects that can be returned by the API.

```
    public List<RunningProcesses> getAllRunningAsyncProcesses() {
    List<Runnable> runningTasks = taskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().stream()
            .map(executor -> ((Runnable) executor))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<RunningProcesses> processes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Runnable task : runningTasks) {
        processes.add(new RunningProcesses(task.toString()));
    }
    return processes;
}
```